# Gatsby links not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am not sure if this is a gatsby problem, I'm pretty new to web development in general. I created a project in gatsby and my global layout has a dark blue background. I added code for an internal link like so:

```
<p>I am a <Link to="/developer/" className={styles.clickity}>Software Developer</Link>
```

and the css class looks like this:

```
.clickity {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AFAF6D;
}
```

The result of this is that the link looks like a deep-fried meme i.e.
[just weird (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdPbS.png)

Is there anything I'm missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has a `text-shadow` property. I'll set `text-shadow: none`

Comment: Yep that fixed it, thanks! I would have never guessed this was the issue.